# How generic interface methods are implemented

Tags: java

```
interface A<T>
{
   void method1(T a)
   {
   }
}
class B implements A<Integer>
{
   void method1(Integer a)
   {
   }
}
```

But at the runtime interface A would like:

```
interface A
{
   void method1(Object a)
   {
   }
}
```

so how `method1` in `class B` is implementing the `method1` in interface A as argument types will be different at runtime. So shouldn't it flag compile error as `method1()` of `interface A` has not implemented.

Comment: Two words - [bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).